# Writing multiple .shps from list with loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, export

I have a list (`mylist`) of about 2000 SpatialPolygonDataFrames and I want to export these .shps in one folder (my directory). I am trying to use a loop in order to access the list but it does not seems to work. How can I do this?

```
for (i in 1:length(mylist)){
    writeOGR(mfiles,i,"mfiles",i,layer = "mfiles",i, driver="ESRI Shapefile",overwrite_layer = T)
}


Error: is.logical(verbose) is not TRUE
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with a list of spatialpointsdataframes, the same will work for your list of spatialpolygondataframes

First load sp and rgdal:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
```

Then create two dummy SpatialPointsDataFrames:

```
coords <- cbind(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 2, 3))
data <- data.frame(name = c("foo", "bar", "blah"))
ob1 = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, data)
coords <- cbind(c(4, 5, 6), c(4, 5, 6))
data <- data.frame(name = c("cookie", "cheese", "apple"))
ob2 = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, data)
```

Then put those two in a list:

```
mfiles <- list(ob1, ob2)
str(mfiles)
```

Now you can use the almost the same code you presented:

```
for (i in 1:length(mfiles)){
    writeOGR(mfiles[[i]],
             paste0("mfiles", i, ".shp"),
             layer = "mfiles",
             driver="ESRI Shapefile",
             overwrite_layer = T)
}
list.files()
```

You were submitting the list itself to the writeOGR function you should index the list in your loop with double square brackets: [[i]]

Comment: Thanks @trosendal for your notice about the index.